# How to locally change equation referencing

Tags: cleveref

Using the `cleveref` package, I created some formatting for constraints.

```
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{cons}{#2constraint~\textup{(#1)}#3}
```

Assume, I have the following equation with a label `my_cons` and the equation number is `(1)`.

```
\begin{equation}\label[cons]{my_cons}
    a+b = 2.
\end{equation}
```

When I use `\cref{my_cons}`, I usually want to see `constraint (1)` and that is what I do with my current layout. But, sometimes, I want to hide the `constraint` part and only display the equation number. How can I locally disable the text part of the cross-reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a cross-reference without generating a name prefix, use `\labelcref`. The commands `\ref` or `\eqref` (assuming `amsmath` is loaded) will do fine as well.

Depending on your formatting preferences, providing a `\labelcrefformat` instruction in the preamble may be a good idea.

For the following screenshot, I've loaded the `hyperref` package and loaded the `cleveref` package with the option `nameinlink`, to better highlight what exactly is being produced by `\labelcref`, `\eqref`, and `\ref`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\eqref" macro
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=red]{hyperref} % optional
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % "nameinlink" optional
\crefformat{cons}{#2constraint~\textup{(#1)}#3}
\labelcrefformat{cons}{\textup{(#2#1#3)}} % or some other suitable choice

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label[cons]{my_cons}
    a+b<2
\end{equation}

\cref{my_cons}

\labelcref{my_cons} or \eqref{my_cons} or \ref{my_cons}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, I read the instructions but could not understand how to implement it. I wish they have explained like you did. Thanks!

Comment: @user8028576 - You're most welcome!